# Vinometer reads 16% while SG says that can't be possible

Tags: wine, yeast

My initial SG was 1.090 and now reads 1.026, this should give me an ABV between 8.4% and 9% but the vinometer is reading 16%, and I have a stuck fermentation with Montrechat (Premier Rouge) yeast (max 13%).

So obviously the vinometer is lying right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vinometers don't work on beer or wine with residual sugars. You need to use a hydrometer. Vinometers only works with dry wine.